# Iptables: how do I LOG what's not being ACCEPTED and limit what gets logged?

Tags: iptables, logging

How do I log what's not being accepted by the following rule:

iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 3 -m -limit --limit 10/minute -j ACCEPT

And how do I limit what's being logged because I don't want to log 1000s of pings?

My first thought was:

iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 3 -m -limit --limit 50/day -j LOG
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 3 -m -limit --limit 10/minute -j ACCEPT

But that doesn't seem right to me.
I think this limits the logging to 50/day but not necessarily what is not being accepted, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To log what *isn't* being accepted by a rule, you put the log rule after the accept rule (because chain processing stops when it hits an accept rule).  To make sure you're logging things that would be accepted by *other* rules, you need to put the accept rule you're testing (and the log rule) at the very top of the chain.

The log limit you've got in place is reasonable, although I would usually prefer something specified per-minute, and with a higher-than-default `limit-burst` (which is 3).